# Where is the golden horn?

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

One of the achievements in Assassin's Creed: Revelations is "Almost Flying" where I must jump from Galata tower to the "Golden Horn."  I know where Galata Tower is, but I haven't seen the "Golden Horn" as a landmark on my map.  Where am I jumping towards?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The **Golden Horn** is the river that separates the top and bottom parts of Constantinople.  You just need to parachute from the top of **Galata Tower** down south all the way to the river.  Note you need to parachute into the river (ride it all the way in), don't drop from the parachute or it won't count.

You can see its name in the **Database** in the **Locations** section toward the end of the list.

Comment: *sigh* seriously?  The giant river?  I can't believe I wasted time trying to figure this out.  Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, took me a while to figure that out, they don't actually use the name **"Golden Horn"** normally, it's in the native name.  I think the user manual actually includes the translation so you'd have to see it there.

Comment: Likely a reference to [Hezârfen Ahmed Çelebi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hez%C3%A2rfen_Ahmed_%C3%87elebi), who took an unpowered flight across the strait.